# SQL Service Broker Queue not Processed

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I followed the [SQL Service Broker Configure](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/asynchronous-triggers-using-sql-broker/) to configure SQL Service Broker in SQL Server 2008. But the queue is not getting processed. It remains in `sys.transmission_queue`. When I check the transmission status it shows the below error.

```
No route matches the destination service name for this conversation. Create a route to the destination service name for messages in this conversation to be delivered.
```

I guess no specific needs to be configured as I am configuring all in the same database inside same server. Any ideas would help.

I checked using ssbdiagnose tool as per Remus Rusanu answer and I am geting the below error

```
An exception occurred on a connection to SQL Server <server name>:Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the SSB diagnostics utility: [`ssbdiagnose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx). Simplest way is to use the `RUNTIME` option and point it to your instance:

```
c:\>ssbdiagnose.exe runtime connect to -E -S <servername>
```

Then wait until it catches a retry and it will start investigating.

You can also try to use the `CONFIGURATION` option, make sure you get the service names right:

```
c:\>ssbdiagnose.exe -E -S <servername> -d <dbname> CONFIGURATION FROM SERVICE <fromservice> TO SERVICE <toservice>
```

Comment: Hi, I checked your answer and am getting authentication error. Kindly see updates in my question. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Use appropriate credentials (`-U`, `-P`). Read the linked documentation.

Comment: Thanks that tool helped to find the error and I created a route now. But now I am getting this error in the queue `<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-8494</Code><Description>You do not have permission to access the service 'ServiceTarget1'.</Description></Error>`